# How to make ends of a beveled curve sharp?

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

I want to make the ends of these curves sharp, and i want it to remain closed even if i move the bevel start and end point of the curves, the curves are generated by ivygen, i want to make it look like they're growing, but i want the ends sharp

Comment: in Curves panel select another curve to be the Taper object

Answer (score 2):

Note: This wont work when you change the bevel begin and end as required. I will let it be posted as an answer if someone else finds it useful.

Depends on your need... this is one way.

Set the Radius to zero on your tip curve vertex.

[image]

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention the curves were generated by ivygen

Comment: And missed the thing where you needed to fiddle with the bevel begin and end :-P